# How to reduce the CPU consumption of my Monero node?

Tags: monerod, nodes, cpu

I have both a testnet and mainnet node running on my Intel i7 CPU, and the CPU is completely maxed out, leaving little room for my other services. Given that the nodes are both in complete sync, what flags could I use to reduce the CPU consumption?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The nodes only really consume high amounts of system resources upon syncing large amounts of blocks. Thus, if you *don't* leave them running continuously, and only start them up occasionally, they will have a larger number of blocks to sync and will therefore require high amounts of system resources.

The simplest *fix* is to leave them running continuously - which is how they are designed to operate. Otherwise you can use make use of various tools, such as `cpulimit`.